# Issue with defining a variable via a TextField and then passing it to an observed object in Simple Swift UI app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have hit a brick wall with on a very simple app with this error. I think that it's probably a common error and is related to a problem in the sequence in my code, but inspite of checking various instances of the error I'm unable to find a similar case to my one that resolves the problem.

The app is an adaptation of an exercise (from SwiftUI for Absolute Beginners by Greg Lim) to make a search call to the Github API and return a list of users. In the original, it supplied a search value, hard coded, and then looks up all the users in Github that it returns. What I wanted to do was turn it into a search app, to be able to dynamically supply the data, so you could choose which users you wanted to look up.

I have adapted this into a single ContentView so that it can be easily run.

I have adapted the observable object class “FetchUsers” to make the request accept a parameter - e.g. the search term - and I have created a textField for the user to enter what will provide this. I have then created an @Binding instance to make this value available in a new view. However, the problem that I’m having is that I’m not able to then instantiate my “fetch” object in the new view.

When I try to do this in the reallyDetailedView I get this error:
Cannot use instance member 'username' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available. As I understand it, when this view is created I have a value to pass to it.

I can see that this is something to do with my initialising the properties in the wrong sequence, but I am not clear how to fix this?

```
    
import SwiftUI
//import URLImage

struct Result: Codable{
    var items: [User] }

struct User: Codable{
    public var login: String
    public var url: String
    public var avatar_url: String
    public var html_url: String }


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var username: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(username: $username)) {
                
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Text("Show detail")
                    }
                    Section {
                        TextField("Enter your username", text: $username)
                        Text("Your username is \(username)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @Binding var username: String
//        @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchUsers(name: username)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let newUsername = username
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Username is:\(username)")
                    Text("New username is:\(newUsername)")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ReallyDetailedView(username: username)) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Get Data button pressed...")
                    }) {
                        Text("Get Data")
                    }
                }
                //                    Text("\(user.url)")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}

class FetchUsers: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [User]()
    var name: String = ""
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=\(name)")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.items = decodedData.items
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}


struct ReallyDetailedView: View {
    
    @Binding var username: String
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchUsers(name: username)
    
//    init(username: String) {
//          self.username = username
//    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        var newUsername = username
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Username is:\(username)")
            Text("New username is:\(newUsername)")
            
        }
        
//        Display the users found using the search term with their photos
//        List(fetch.items, id: \.login) { user in
//            Link(destination: URL(string: user.html_url)!){
//                HStack(alignment: .top){
//                    URLImage(URL(string:user.avatar_url)!){ image in image.resizable().frame(width: 50, height: 50)
//                    }
    }
}
```

Incidentially, I do think that I can do all of this in two views but I created a third one so as to be completely sure that the username property had been established before I made the data call. Inspite of this, I seem to have misunderstood something in what is required.

Any advice, or links to examples that achieve what I am trying to do would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you searched SO for similar errors and issues? There must be a truck load of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to perform the search from the `init` isn't really going to work as you have found.

Rather, have a `search` function.  You can invoke this from an `.onAppear` closure in your detail view:

```
class FetchUsers: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    func search(for user:String) {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.github.com/search/users")!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: user)]
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = decodedData.items
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
             
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Enter user to search for")
                    TextField("Enter your username", text: $username)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(username: $username)) {
                    Text("Show detail for \(username)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @Binding var username: String
    @ObservedObject var fetchUsers = FetchUsers()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(fetchUsers.users, id:\.self) { user in
                NavigationLink(user.login, destination: UserDetailView(user:user))
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.fetchUsers.search(for: username)
        }
        
    }
}

struct UserDetailView: View {
    
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(user.login).font(.headline)
            Text("Score = \(user.score)")
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, here are my `Codable` structs that I generated with https://app.quicktype.io.  I added conformance to `Hashable` so that I could use `ForEach`

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let totalCount: Int
    let incompleteResults: Bool
    let items: [User]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
        case items
    }
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable, Hashable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let nodeID: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let gravatarID: String
    let url, htmlURL, followersURL: String
    let followingURL, gistsURL, starredURL: String
    let subscriptionsURL, organizationsURL, reposURL: String
    let eventsURL: String
    let receivedEventsURL: String
    let type: String
    let siteAdmin: Bool
    let score: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, id
        case nodeID = "node_id"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case gravatarID = "gravatar_id"
        case url
        case htmlURL = "html_url"
        case followersURL = "followers_url"
        case followingURL = "following_url"
        case gistsURL = "gists_url"
        case starredURL = "starred_url"
        case subscriptionsURL = "subscriptions_url"
        case organizationsURL = "organizations_url"
        case reposURL = "repos_url"
        case eventsURL = "events_url"
        case receivedEventsURL = "received_events_url"
        case type
        case siteAdmin = "site_admin"
        case score
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That looks like that could work in principal, but I'm getting some errors when I try to run it - I think that there is something missing?

Comment: What errors?  This is basically code that I pasted in from my working version of the app.  My code has a more complete `User` structure and refers to the `score` property that you don't have.  I also added `Hashable` conformance to my `User` struct.  I have added my structs to the answer.

Comment: Ah, my bad! I had somehow managed to remove one of the structs and that was breaking it. It is building now. Many thanks!